# _open fails with O_TRUNC when file exists and is synced with onedrive

Tags: c++, c, windows, onedrive

I have found the following behaviour and would like to find out why the function call fails and if there is a fix or workaround.

I have isolated the behaviour with the following minimal C/C++ code snippet

```
#include<io.h>
int main()
{
    char path[] = "C:\\Users\\<my_username>\\OneDrive - <my_employer>\\Documents\\file.bin";
    int fh = _open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_BINARY, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
    if (fh >= 0)
    {
        _write(fh, "somebytes", 9);
        _close(fh);
    }
    else
    {
        int err = errno;
        char* message = strerror(err);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have removed my username and my employer name from my onedrive folder for anonymity.

If the file does not already exist, then the file is creates a file and filled with the appropriate text as expected.

If the file exists, but has not yet been synced to my onedrive then the file is opened, truncated and filled with the appropriate text as expected.

**However, if the file exist and has been synced to my onedrive, the `_open` call fails and `errno` is set to `EINVAL` (invalid argument).**

Removing `O_TRUNC` from the `_open` call stops the function from failing, but does not have the required behaviour. I.e. the file is not truncated before writing.

It is perhaps worth noting that from the microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen, `EINVAL` seems a strange error code to set, given the symptoms.

My OneDrive is version 2021 (Build 21.150.0725.0001 64 bit)

Has anyone experienced this problem before and have a solution or workaround?

In my particular case, code like the snippet above is used as part of the netcdf/hdf5 file format library and this is causing my file writes to fail. Also I have had a problem where I cannot  store visual studio projects in my onedrive folder, because once they sync, various files cannot be overwritten during the build process - I now wonder if this is due to the same issue.

Edit - I do not seem to have the same problem on my home PC. Only on my work computer - is the business version of OneDrive built upon Sharepoint? Perhaps this makes a difference if so.

Comment: The test should really be `fh >= 0`, since 0 is a valid file descriptor, but that is probably not the real issue.

Comment: Thanks - edited to the code. But you are correct, this isn't the issue in question here as the file descriptor was returning either 3 or -1 in my tests.

Comment: GetLastError should give a more accurate error code than errno. Also check out _chsize and SetEndOfFile.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you don't use One Drive to "backup" source code and instead use a source control system - [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [Azure Dev Ops](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/) both have free versions available

Comment: The issue with visual studio is only one symptom of the problem. Plus good practice in git is to commit changes as useful meaningful changes, not just as hourly or daily backups. Source control and backing up are two different things.